# Add date in rows where date is missing based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with time series data. In one column I have signup dates, and in the other cancel dates. I want to add a date for missing cancel dates that is less than a specific date, but maximum 40 weeks.

How should I proceed?

if `df['cancel_date']` is `NaT`, then add date max. + 40 weeks.
`df['cancel_date'] - df['signup_date']` should not be less than 0.

Comment: Do you have an example of your `df` (with some rows with missing data)?

Comment: What do you mean with `date.max`? Is this the max of `df['signup_date']` or `df['cancel_date']`?

Comment: with `date.max` I mean the date should not be larger than e.g. 2018-04-30 - for `df['cancel_date']`

Comment: I still don't get it. Where does `2018-04-30` come from? You say that solution 1 of Chris A works, but this doesn't use anything with max. do you actualy need anything with max? And if you just use the signup_date from the corresponding row. How can it be less than 0 if you add 40 weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) class.

If adding 40 weeks to the records `signup_date`:

```
df['cancel_date'] = df['cancel_date'].fillna(df['signup_date'] + pd.Timedelta(40, 'W'))
```

If adding 40 weeks to maximum date in the `sign_up` column:

```
df['cancel_date'] = df['cancel_date'].fillna(df['signup_date'].max() + pd.Timedelta(40, 'W'))
```

Or if using some predefined `max date` value, with the constraint that `signup_date < cancel_date`, chain on the [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) method:

```
max_date = pd.datetime(2018, 4, 30)

df['cancel_date'] = df['cancel_date'].fillna(max_date + pd.Timedelta(40, 'W')).clip(lower=df.signup_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `numpy.where`, if you want to append a difference column directly between singup date and cancel date:

```
df['date difference between signup and cancel'] = np.where(df['cancel_date'] == np.nan, (df['signup_date'].max() + pd.Timedelta(40, 'W'))-df['signup_date'], df['cancel_date']-df['signup_date'])
```

This will give you a new column where you would have directly the difference between the signup date and the cancel date

Comment: datemax is missing, he could also applay another numpy where in it

Comment: This still doesn't do what he asks. If `df['cancel_date']` is NaN, how can you subtract `(df['signup_date'].max() + pd.Timedelta(40, 'W'))` from it? And als the `y` part of `np.where()` isn't correct. If df['cancel_date']` is a date, than it should just be df['cancel_date']` (and not `df['cancel_date']-df['signup_date']`).

Comment: other way around now, i am not sure what he asked for

Comment: if he asked just to fillna with a logic, the above solution is correc,t if he needs to add another column, mine is not bad